# Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. "Numeric Code: 2"

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I've spent some time sorting and deleting emails from my Gmail account.

Suddenly, I get an error that the gmail account is "temporarily unavailable" with "Numeric Code: 2".

[image: Numeric Code: 2]

> We're sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes. You can view the [G Suite Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/) for the current status of the service.
>
> If the issue persists, please visit the Gmail Help Center
>
> Try Again Sign Out
>
> Hide Detailed Technical Info
> **Numeric Code: 2**

How can can I regain access to the Gmail account? How long does this temporary unavailability take to resolve?

Comment: Have you followed the directions of the message? How long have you waited before trying again? When was the last time that you tried? Have you viewed the "G Suite Status Dashboard" as was suggested in the message?

Comment: Just got same error, did it work for you after some time ?

Comment: @Pரதீப் this happened to me some time ago, I was just reminded of it when someone else hit it. I've now asked it to seed Stack Exchange with the question. Please Answer with your own timeline if/when it resolves itself...